# Text is dropped after the first word in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have created custom themes for WordPress. When I passed value to the input Text Box WordPress is removing the all the texts, words after the first word!??

Here is the code:

```
 $text_message = "Check out our cool products."
```

**For the above text message it just only prints "Check"!! the rest words "out our cool products." are not displayed in the input textbox??**

HTML Code is here:

```
 <a style="float: right; margin-top:52px; margin-right:-230px; width: 32px;height: 32px; background-image: url(../wp-content/images/twiiter_logo.png)"
 href=<?=$text_message;?>  class="login" title=""></a>
```

Have you guys also experienced the same? How it can be fixed?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Variable is not echoed properly. I believe that value is text in the link, not href. In the `href`, display proper URL.

Try this:

```
<a style="float: right; margin-top:52px; margin-right:-230px; width: 32px;height: 32px; background-image: url(../wp-content/images/twiiter_logo.png)" href="#" class="login" title="">
<?php echo $text_message; ?>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a simple mistake!

I finally could find it out. I just need to put the php variable inside the single quotation (' ') mark! That's it!

Here is the solution :

```
<a style="float: right; margin-top:52px; margin-right:-230px; width:     32px;height: 32px; background-image: url(../wp-content/images/twiiter_logo.png)"
href='<?=$text_message;?>'  class="login" title=""></a>
```